# Excel 2010: Change default format of today's date shortcut format

Tags: excel, date, excel-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, date-formatting

**Question**: How do I change the default of the date format using the Excel shortcut [Ctrl] + [;]? In other words, a "insert  today's date as dd-MMM-yyyy at cursor placement" solution.

Currently, it is set to dd-mm-yy.

I use Windows 7 Enterprise (SP1).

**Reason**: I want it to be dd-MMM-yyyy, as this is corporate standard. I am often using this shortcut *in a cell with other text*, so a cell date formatting isn't feasible.

Examples:

- [Example of how I would write today](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWEa9.png)
- [Example of how I would like to write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pWX2.png)

**Tried so far:** I've have the "short date" in Control Panel -> Region and Language set to dd-MMM-yyyy, so this is obviously not where the formatting is defined.

**PS**: This is my first post on stackoverflow. Please let me know, in a respectful way, if I should have written/structured this post differently.

Comment: You could write vba code that use the same shortcut to override the standard.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using ??

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. Sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: You need to look into regex to pull out and replace the text in the format you want.  Try writing it on your own.  Your question originally was specific enough that a one line code would answer it, now you are asking someone to write a fairly complex code for you.  That is not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: Thanks for hinting the direction to go. My question was always the same, I simply elaborated on it as several people misunderstood my question. I was not aware that it was such a complex code, as I my programming knowledge is quite low. I know that Stack Overflow is not for requesting big complex codes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your Language and Regions settings from the Control Panel:

[image]

Getting there varies with the version of Windows.

Comment: I have already done this. I changed the Short date to dd-MMM-yyyy. The result in Excel is still dd-mm-yy.

Comment: @MichaelKristensen  Did you re-start your computer ??

Comment: I changed the Short date several months ago in efforts to solve this minor annoyance and have restarted my computer several time since. I'm just having a separate stab at it now due to a slow Friday at work :-) I can try restarting again?

Comment: @MichaelKristensen  Yes.............This is of interest to me......... **please update this question if you find an answer**

Answer (score 0):

Scott's suggestion is good. This worked for me:

**EDIT**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Len(Target) <= 10 Then
    Target.NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
Else
    Target = Replace(Target, Date, Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yyyy"))
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Place the above code in the Worksheet object

Comment: Thanks for writing the code. However, I use the shortcut in a cell. So I write something like this:
"21-Oct-2016, Michael: It was decided that XYZ.

Comment: *in a cell together with other text. And I write multiple updates, each with a date as the first part of the line, in the same cell.

Comment: Would it be possible to write a "print todays date as dd-MMM-yyyy at cursor" in Excel, similar to this in Word, [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778442/how-do-i-insert-text-at-my-cursor-location-in-word[link].

Comment: @MichaelKristensen I changed the code to change mid text. But it will only work for the current date.